# Is it possible to use a profile based filter in your web.xml

Tags: java, servlets, spring-security, web.xml

Is it possible to use a profile based filter in your web.xml ? For example

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
         <init-param>
            <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
            <param-value>secured</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
```

I know this is possible for servlets, but I cant seem to get it to work for filters.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Original Answer

Filters use the ApplicationContext loaded from the ContextLoaderListener, so the `<init-param>` to the Filter is not used. Instead, you will want to use one of the ways of activating the profile for the ContextLoaderListener. One way is to use a  as shown below:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
    <param-value>secured</param-value>
</context-param>
```

## Follow Up

Following up based upon the comments. There is no way to omit the Filter using Spring profiles since the web.xml will always load the DelegatingFilterProxy which always tries to load its delegate. If the delegate is missing you will get an error. Instead, you can create a profile that disable Spring Security as shown below:

```
<b:beans profile="default,secured">
  <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
  </http>
  <authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
      <user-service>
        <user name="user" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
      </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
  </authentication-manager>
</b:beans>
<b:beans profile="insecure">
  <http security="none" />
</b:beans>
```

You could then disable Spring Security by activating the insecure profile in your web.xml as shown below.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
    <param-value>insecure</param-value>
</context-param>
```

If you are not using Spring Security you can disable the Filter by creating a Filter that does nothing but continue the FilterChain an placing that in the disabled profile. For example:

```
public class DoFilterChainFilter implements Filter {
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
    public void destroy() { }
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException { }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So its not possible to only instantiate the filter in certain profiles?

Comment: I'm not certain I understand the question. The profile will impact the entire configuration, but you can impact only the filter by only using a profile for the filter.

Comment: Yes but imagine I want the profile to determine whether to instantiate the filter or not.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand. The question asked if it is possible to use a profile based filter. Are you asking what the configuration should look like if you want it completely disabled?

Comment: Yes, sort of. Obviously its possible to instantiate 2 different beans for the filter-class based on a profile. This, as you say, is taken from the context-param. Imagine though you wanted the filter to be disabled if the profile wasn't active. What would the configuration look like ?

Comment: Thankyou, thats exactly what I ended up doing.